# Apache cannot start

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I installed xampp in this path (C:\m_server\xampp)
When I start from control panel, the following error occur

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
```

Then I start httpd.exe from cmd the following error occurs. How to solve this error?

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 531 of C:/m_server/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 17 of C:/m_server/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load /xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: \x8ew\x92\xe8\x82\xb3\x82\xea\x82\xbd\\xc2\x82\xa9\x82\xe8\x82\xdc\x82\xb9\x82\xf1\x81B
```

Comment: That means php7ts.dll is missing on that path, so just comment out that line in httpd-xampp.conf and try again

Comment: @AhmedGinani When comment out the error changed as this (Syntax error on line 72 of C:/m_server/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_access_compat.so into server:)

Comment: Just run setup_xampp.bat from shell and try again

Comment: @AhmedGinani Hey guy, thank you very much. You really saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run setup_xammp.bat from cmd and the problem is automatically fixed. Like this,

```
C:\m_server\xampp>setup_xampp.bat
```