# xmapp showing only the backend codes

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

my xampp was working fine until recently when i had problem with my apache so i commented out php5ts.dll and php5apache2_4.dll in the httpd-xampp file, after that, when i run my program , the browser when automatically process it, and show the backend codes along side the frontend designs. On the other-hand when i open my WordPress file it will show me only the backend codes. please i need to know if there is any i can do to shop this.

This is what the browser is showing me when i open the WordPress " 'Welcome to your WordPress Dashboard! This is the screen you will see when you log in to your site, and gives you access to all the site management features of WordPress. You can get help for any screen by clicking the Help tab above the screen title.' ) . ' '; $screen = get_current_screen(); $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'overview', 'title' => __( 'Overview' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); // Help tabs $help = ' ' . __( 'The left-hand navigation menu provides links to all of the WordPress administration screens, with submenu items displayed on hover. You can minimize this menu to a narrow icon strip by clicking on the Collapse Menu arrow at the bottom.' ) . '

'; $help .= ' ' . __( 'Links in the Toolbar at the top of the screen connect your dashboard and the front end of your site, and provide access to your profile and helpful WordPress information.' ) . '

'; $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'help-navigation', 'title' => __( 'Navigation' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); $help = ' ' . __( 'You can use the following controls to arrange your Dashboard screen to suit your workflow. This is true on most other administration screens as well.' ) . '

'; $help .= ' ' . __( 'Screen Options — Use the Screen Options tab to choose which Dashboard boxes to show.' ) . '

'; $help .= ' ' . __( 'Drag and Drop — To rearrange the boxes, drag and drop by clicking on the title bar of the selected box and releasing when you see a gray dotted-line rectangle appear in the location you want to place the box.' ) . '

'; $help .= ' ' . __( 'Box Controls — Click the title bar of the box to expand or collapse it. Some boxes added by plugins may have configurable content, and will show a “Configure” link in the title bar if you hover over it.' ) . '

'; $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'help-layout', 'title' => __( 'Layout' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); $help = ' ' . __( 'The boxes on your Dashboard screen are:' ) . '

'; if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) $help .= ' ' . __( 'At A Glance — Displays a summary of the content on your site and identifies which theme and version of WordPress you are using.' ) . '

'; $help .= ' ' . __( 'Activity — Shows the upcoming scheduled posts, recently published posts, and the most recent comments on your posts and allows you to moderate them.' ) . '

'; if ( is_blog_admin() && current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) $help .= ' ' . __( "Quick Draft — Allows you to create a new post and save it as a draft. Also displays links to the 5 most recent draft posts you've started." ) . '

'; if ( ! is_multisite() && current_user_can( 'install_plugins' ) ) $help .= ' ' . sprintf( /* translators: %s: WordPress Planet URL */ __( 'WordPress News — Latest news from the official WordPress project, the WordPress Planet, and popular plugins.' ), __( 'https://planet.wordpress.org/' ) ) . '

'; else $help .= ' ' . sprintf( /* translators: %s: WordPress Planet URL */ __( 'WordPress News — Latest news from the official WordPress project and the WordPress Planet.' ), __( 'https://planet.wordpress.org/' ) ) . '

'; if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) $help .= ' ' . __( 'Welcome — Shows links for some of the most common tasks when setting up a new site.' ) . '

'; $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'help-content', 'title' => __( 'Content' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); unset( $help ); $screen->set_help_sidebar( ' ' . __( 'For more information:' ) . '

' . ' ' . __( 'Documentation on Dashboard' ) . '

' . ' ' . __( 'Support Forums' ) . '

' ); include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php' ); ?> user_email != get_option( 'admin_email' ) ); if ( $hide ) $classes .= ' hidden'; ?> ""

Comment: Your apache is not executing the php-code. You need php to be working, commenting out the php-dll is NOT an option...

Comment: @HampusBrynolf if i dont comment out the php-dll then my apache will not start all all, because i have tried it before, please what advise will you give on that

Comment: see if [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603843/apache-cannot-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603843/apache-cannot-start) helps

Comment: @Andra the setup_xampp.bat did not solve the problem but thanks anyway, please is there any other solution

Comment: what problem did you have with apache? You cannot comment out php-dlls and hope it works.

Comment: @Andra apache couldn't start so when i checked shell i saw an error which made me comment out those line , apache worked after commenting then out but i was seeing my backend codes each time i load any project

Comment: thus your problem is _apache couldn't start_ and not backend codes

Comment: @ yea, i was getting error at LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"

Comment: the backend happened when i commented out the .dll files

Comment: check this path `C:/xampp/php/`. Is there `php5ts.dll` file?

Comment: yea there is, i saw the file there

Comment: maybe it's a bad idea but you could try other versions of the file [http://originaldll.com/search?q=php5ts.dll](http://originaldll.com/search?q=php5ts.dll). In case yours is corrupted. And backup the current files.

Comment: how can i know the version to down?

Comment: my xampp is v3.2.1

Comment: Find the version of the actual file - select php5ts.dll, press right mouse, you should see Properties or smth like that.

Comment: i cannot see my version there, mine is 5.6.8.0

Comment: google "download php5ts.dll" and choose a bit older version

Comment: ok lemme check on google

Comment: @Andra i cann't see the exact version on google

Comment: Reinstall xampp from scratch.

Comment: Forget it with changing dlls (I'm not even sure Windows allows that). Either reinstall like Hampus says or, if it doesn't help, post a question in superuser or serverfault community.

Comment: thanks so much guys, i will do just that